# Sortorder in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have written elasticsearch query using java api in which status count is fetched per day.

Code:

```
SearchResponse responseOutput = client.prepareSearch(ConstantsValue.indexName)
.setTypes(ConstantsValue._Type)
.setFetchSource(new String[]{"STATUS", "DTCREATED"}, null)
.setQuery(
    QueryBuilders.filteredQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery(),
    FilterBuilders.rangeFilter("DTCREATED").from(fromDate).to(toDate))).
    addAggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms("STATUS_AGG").field("STATUS")
        .subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.dateHistogram("DATE_AGG").field("DTCREATED").interval(DateHistogram.Interval.DAY).format("yyyy-MM-dd"))
        )
       .addSort("DTCREATED", SortOrder.ASC)
       .get();
```

I am trying to sort data by DTCREATED field which contains both date and time but query does not provide sorted result. I can't find what I am missing in query. Any help ?

Comment: Are you getting any error or exception ?

Answer (score 0):

What if you have your `.addSort` as below:

```
.addSort(SortBuilders.fieldSort("DTCREATED").order(SortOrder.ASC))
```

Few samples [here](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.elasticsearch.search.sort.SortOrder) might help you.